# Adding elements from one array to another array

Tags: flutter

I have a list of data array from an API and I need to check the id with another hardcoded data array id.And I need to add two data elements which I'm getting from the api data array to the hardcoded array.

This is the hardcoded data array.

```
List<Data> data = [
  Data(id: 1, title: 'title 1', comment: null, selected: null),
  Data(id: 2, title: 'title 2', comment: null, selected: null),
  Data(id: 3, title: 'title 3', val: null, comment: null, selected: null),
];
```

This is the data response from the API.

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "value 1",
            "comment": "comment 1",
            "userId": 1,
        
        },
    {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "value 2",
            "comment": "comment 2",
            "userId": 2,
        
        },
    {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "value 3",
            "comment": "comment 3",
            "userId": 3,
        
        },
]
```

What I wanna do is the value I'm getting for comment and value from this response data list to add to the hardcoded array comment and selected.They're initially null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a dynamic list

```
  List<dynamic> data = [
    { 'id': 1, 'title': 'title 1', 'comment': null, 'selected': null },
    { 'id': 2, 'title': 'title 2', 'comment': null, 'selected': null },
    { 'id': 3, 'title': 'title 3', 'val': null, 'comment': null, 'selected': null},
  ];
```

and the response from api is

```
List<dynamic> apiResp = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "value 1",
      "comment": "comment 1",
      "userId": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "value 2",
      "comment": "comment 2",
      "userId": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "value 3",
      "comment": "comment 3",
      "userId": 3,
    },
  ];
```

to update the comment and selected fields from api response you can do something like this

```
  for (var each in data) {
     var index = apiResp.indexWhere((element) => element!['id']!.toString() == each!['id']!.toString());
     if (index > -1) {
       data[index]!['comment'] = apiResp[index]!['comment'];
       data[index]!['selected'] = apiResp[index]!['selected'];
     }
  }
```

if you want to make sure your data is updated just print it like this

```
  // print to ensure the data is update
  for (var each in data) {
    print(each);
  }
```

Note: I added `.toString` with id incase if you are not sure about data type and also if your response from api is not in list form you can convert it,

```
 var data = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
 return data.toList();
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response.Data is updating but not to the one with the same id.I want only to update the data that have the same id

Comment: I am using `indexWhere` to find the index by matching the id of both document before updating the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time.Had to change it like this. :) **for (var each in data) {
     var index = apiResp.indexWhere((element) => element!['id']!.toString() == each!['id']!.toString());
     if (index > -1) {
       data[index]!['comment'] = apiResp[index]!['comment'];
       data[index]!['selected'] = apiResp[index]!['selected'];
     }
  }**